# JComponent global method GET doesn't work in Total.js Flow components

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

I have a problem in Total.js Flow using inside a component the client-side method GET to retrieve value of JComponent ( in my case textbox or input ).
I have tried from Componentator and actually works, but inside my Total.js Flow ( version 6, but the 5 version has the same problem ) it return undefined. Someone know any solution or better way to retrieve for example on button click the value inside the input box?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div data-jc="textbox" data-jc-path="url">@(URL)</div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <button onclick="getUrl()">Try</button>     // this call an example function that call the "console.log"


console.log(GET('url'));    // return undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flow** uses jComponent scopes in the form `settings.NAME_OF_COMPONENT.path`. So you can use `GET('settings.name_of_component.url')` or you can use a direct call like `console.log(settings.name_of_component.url)`.